# Computing limits in matrix exponential

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, banach-spaces, normed-spaces, matrix-exponential

If $A \in B(V)$ where $V$ is a Banach space, and $B(V)$ is set of all bounded linear operators on $V$, then show if $lim_{n→\infty} A_n=A$, then $lim_{n→\infty}(I+\frac{A_n}{n})^n = exp(A)$

I am very new in learning matrix exponentials and norm linear spaces, and but I can't approach.

Obviously $(I+\frac{A_n}{n})^n$ is bounded .

A small help is appreciated .

Comment: Do you know how to prove this when $A_n$ and $A$ are simply complex numbers?

Comment: @MaoWao, I was trying to prove using DCT, (dominated convergence theorem), but got stuck at a point

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to prove it:

**Step 1):** For each fixed complex number $z$ have have $(1 + \frac{z}{n})^n \to \exp(z)$; this is simply Euler's formula.

**Step 2):** If $|z| \le R$ for a real number $R \ge 0$, then
$$
  \big|(1 + \frac{z}{n})^n\big| \le \big(1 + \frac{R}{n}\big)^n \to \exp(R).
$$
This shows that the sequence $\big((1 + \frac{z}{n})^n\big)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is uniformly bounded for $z$ in any fixed compact subset of the complex plane.

Hence, the convergence $(1 + \frac{z}{n})^n \to \exp(z)$ is uniform on compact subsets of $\mathbb{C}$ by Step 1) and Montel's theorem.

**Step 3):** General observation:

If $(f_n)$ is a sequence of entire functions which converges to $0$ uniformly on compact subsets of $\mathbb{C}$, then for each number $R \ge 0$,
$$
  \sup\big\{ \|f_n(C)\|: \, C \in B(V), \; \|C\| \le R \big\} \to 0
  \quad \text{as } n \to \infty.
$$
Indeed, this follows from the Cauchy formula representation of the functional calculus, i.e.,
$$
  f_n(C) = \frac{1}{2\pi i} \oint_{|z| = {R+1}} f_n(z) (z-C)^{-1} \, dz.
$$
(Use that boundedness of the resolvent $(z-C)^{-1}$ on the circle $|z| = R+1$ follows from $\|C\| \le R$ and from the Neumann series representation of the resolvent.

**Step 4):**
Use a $2\varepsilon$-argument: For each index $n$, we have
$$
  \left\|(1 + \frac{A_n}{n})^n - \exp(A)\right\|
  \le
  \left\|(1 + \frac{A_n}{n})^n - \exp(A_n)\right\|
  +
  \left\| \exp(A_n) - \exp(A) \right\|.
$$
The first summand converges to $0$ according to Steps 2) and 3) above, and the second summand converges to $0$ due to the continuity of the operator exponential function.